# Passing data to Attachment in laravel

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5

I am trying to generate an invoice pdf and attach it to an email. However, I have a challenge passing the data to the PDF attachment. See below;

```
$data = array('org_name' => $org_name, 'org_commission' => $org_commission );

$emails = $users->email;
$amount_topUp = $request->amount_topUp;

Mail::send('emails.setting', $data, function ($m) use ($emails) {
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('PDF.topUp',['amount_topUp' => $amount_topUp])->stream();
        $m->attachData($pdf, 'TopUp' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '.pdf');
        $m->to($emails)->subject('Account Top Up Notification.');
    });
```

This fails with **Undefined variable: amount_topUp**. The variable is defined. I feel it is my passing that is wrong however can not thing of another way.

Howerver when I remove the parameter passed to PDF, everything works as a PDF is generated; but no variable is passed which does not achieve the point.

Anyone help out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing `$amount_topUp` using `use` keyword

```
Mail::send('emails.setting', $data, function ($m) use ($emails,$amount_topUp) {
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView('PDF.topUp',['amount_topUp' => $amount_topUp])->stream();
        $m->attachData($pdf, 'TopUp' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . '.pdf');
        $m->to($emails)->subject('Account Top Up Notification.');
    });
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked!